# Modify value in a class then use it in another form

Tags: c#, winforms

I have form1, form2 and a class. i want to use form2 to modify a variable in a class then read that variable in form1.

The thing is that the variable doesn't change when i try to read it from form1, nor it stays after i open form2 again.

This is my code:

Form1

```
namespace app1 {
public partial class Form1 : Form {
    Class1 md = new Class1();

    public Form1() {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void loginToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        Login login = new Login();
        login.MdiParent = this;
        login.enbctrs += new ShowFrm(enablecrts);
        login.disctrs += new ShowFrm(disablecrts);
        login.Show();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {            
        if (md.user == null) {
            disablecrts();
            stat_usr.Text = "No active user";
        } else {
            stat_usr.Text = md.user.ToString();
        }
    }

    void disablecrts() {
        stat_usr.Text = "No active user";
    }

    void enablecrts() {
        stat_usr.Text = md.user;       
    }
}}
```

Form2

```
namespace app1.Forms {
public delegate void ShowFrm();
public partial class Login : Form {

    public event ShowFrm enbctrs;
    public event ShowFrm disctrs;
    int ing_counter = 0;
    Class1 md = new Class1();
    public Login() {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        string u = "user";
        string p = "pass";
        if(Txt_user.Text == u && Txt_pass.Text == p) {
            string msg = "Welcome: " + u + "";
            MessageBox.Show(msg, "", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
            md.changeusr(u);                
            active_user.Text = md.user.ToString();
            enbctrs();
        }

    private void Login_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        if (md.user == null) {
            active_user.Text = "No active user";
        } else {
            active_user.Text = md.user.ToString();
        }
    }
}}
```

Class1

```
namespace app1.Modules {
class Class1 {
    public string user;
    public void changeusr(string u) {
        user = u;
        return;                  
    }          
}}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish. You're "newing" your Class1 instance with every page load. You need some sort of persistence mechanism.

Comment: You should be using static class and members to retain its value. Or else you would be saving the current state in XML and load it every time.

Comment: Here's a page that might help you: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6c3yckfw.aspx.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of things that could be improved in your code. But the main issue is that when you create the `Login` class in your `loginToolStripMenuItem_Click()` method, that new `Login` instance is also creating a new instance of `Class1` and using that instead of the instance that your `Form1` knows about. So when `Login` changes the user value, it's changing it in a location that `Form1` doesn't know anything about.

The simplest fix IMHO is to have `Form1` just pass the `Class1` reference to `Login` for it to use, instead of having `Login` create its own instance. For example:

```
public partial class Login : Form {
    // ...

    readonly Class1 md;
    public Login(Class1 md) {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.md = md;
    }

    // ...
}
```

And in `Form1`:

```
private void loginToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    Login login = new Login(md);
    login.MdiParent = this;
    login.enbctrs += new ShowFrm(enablecrts);
    login.disctrs += new ShowFrm(disablecrts);
    login.Show();
}
```

Then when `Login` changes the user and raises the event, it will have changed the value in the same instance `Form1` is using, and so `Form1` will get the desired value in its own code.

Answer (score -1):

```
public static class global{
    public static int myInt = 0;
}
public class Form1{
     global.myInt = 10;
}
public class Form2{
      Console.WriteLine(global.myInt.ToString());
}
```

Comment: A code dump is not helpful. Please explain how your code here applies to the question? Ignoring for a moment that global variables are about the worst way for objects to communicate with each other, how does the global variable you propose fix the problem the OP describes?